# How to resize/rescale an image loaded into microsoft visual studio 2019 using the win32 library?

Tags: c, winapi, image-processing

I have an image to load into my GUI, using the win32 library. It's too large and so the entire image does not get displayed.

Below is the code for the window and painting the image onto the window.

The target image is 1600 pixels wide and 1140 pixels tall.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg,
        WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)

{
HMENU               hMenu;
OPENFILENAME        ofn;
FILE                *fpt;
HDC                 hDC;
char                header[320],text[320];
int                 BYTES,xPos,yPos;

switch (uMsg)
  {
  case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
      {
      case ID_FILE_CLEARIMAGE:
        //Clear image
        PaintImage();
        break;
      case ID_FILE_LOAD:
        if (OriginalImage != NULL || image_loaded == 1)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1500; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 1500; j++)
                {
                    OriginalImage[i * COLS + j] = 255;
                }
            }
            OriginalImage = NULL;
            free(OriginalImage);
          }
        memset(&(ofn),0,sizeof(ofn));
        ofn.lStructSize=sizeof(ofn);
        ofn.lpstrFile=filename;
        filename[0]=0;
        ofn.nMaxFile=MAX_FILENAME_CHARS;
        ofn.Flags=OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_HIDEREADONLY;
        ofn.lpstrFilter = "PNM files\0*.pnm\0All files\0*.*\0\0";
        if (!( GetOpenFileName(&ofn))  ||  filename[0] == '\0')
          break;        /* user cancelled load */
        if ((fpt=fopen(filename,"rb")) == NULL)
          {
          MessageBox(NULL,"Unable to open file",filename,MB_OK | MB_APPLMODAL);
          break;
          }
        fscanf(fpt,"%s\n%d %d\n%d",header,&COLS,&ROWS,&BYTES);
        if (strcmp(header,"P6") != 0  ||  BYTES != 255)
          {
          MessageBox(NULL,"Not a PNM image",filename,MB_OK | MB_APPLMODAL);
          fclose(fpt);
          break;
          }
        OriginalImage=(unsigned char *)calloc(ROWS*COLS*3,1);
        header[0]=fgetc(fpt);   /* whitespace character after header */
        fread(OriginalImage,1,ROWS*COLS*3,fpt);
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            {
                OriginalImage[i * COLS + j] = (int)(OriginalImage[i * (COLS * 3) + (j * 3)] + 
                    OriginalImage[i * (COLS * 3) + (j * 3) + 1] + 
                    OriginalImage[i * (COLS * 3) + (j * 3) + 2])/3.0;
            }
        }
        image_loaded = 1;
        fclose(fpt);
        SetWindowText(hWnd,filename);
        PaintImage();
        break;

      case ID_FILE_QUIT:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
      }
    break;
  case WM_SIZE:       /* could be used to detect when window size changes */
    PaintImage();
    return(DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam));
    break;
  case WM_PAINT:
    PaintImage();
    return(DefWindowProc(hWnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam));
    break;
```

Below is the paint function

```
void PaintImage()

{
PAINTSTRUCT         Painter;
HDC                 hDC;
BITMAPINFOHEADER    bm_info_header;
BITMAPINFO          *bm_info;
int                 i,r,c,DISPLAY_ROWS,DISPLAY_COLS;
unsigned char       *DisplayImage;
HDC                 hdcScaled;
HBITMAP             hbmScaled;


if (OriginalImage == NULL)
  return;       /* no image to draw */

        /* Windows pads to 4-byte boundaries.  We have to round the size up to 4 in each dimension, filling with black. */
DISPLAY_ROWS=ROWS;
DISPLAY_COLS=COLS;
if (DISPLAY_ROWS % 4 != 0)
  DISPLAY_ROWS=(DISPLAY_ROWS/4+1)*4;
if (DISPLAY_COLS % 4 != 0)
  DISPLAY_COLS=(DISPLAY_COLS/4+1)*4;
DisplayImage=(unsigned char *)calloc(DISPLAY_ROWS*DISPLAY_COLS,1);
for (r=0; r<ROWS; r++)
  for (c=0; c<COLS; c++)
    DisplayImage[r*DISPLAY_COLS+c] = OriginalImage[r*COLS+c];

BeginPaint(MainWnd,&Painter);
hDC=GetDC(MainWnd); 
bm_info_header.biSize=sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
bm_info_header.biWidth=DISPLAY_COLS;
bm_info_header.biHeight=-DISPLAY_ROWS; 
bm_info_header.biPlanes=1;
bm_info_header.biBitCount=8; 
bm_info_header.biCompression=BI_RGB; 
bm_info_header.biSizeImage=0; 
bm_info_header.biXPelsPerMeter=0; 
bm_info_header.biYPelsPerMeter=0;
bm_info_header.biClrUsed=256;
bm_info_header.biClrImportant=256;
bm_info=(BITMAPINFO *)calloc(1,sizeof(BITMAPINFO) + 256*sizeof(RGBQUAD));
bm_info->bmiHeader=bm_info_header;
for (i=0; i<256; i++)
  {
  bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = i;
  bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved=0;
  } 
 
SetDIBitsToDevice(hDC,0,0,DISPLAY_COLS,DISPLAY_ROWS,0,0,
              0, /* first scan line */
              DISPLAY_ROWS, /* number of scan lines */
              DisplayImage,bm_info,DIB_RGB_COLORS);
hdcScaled = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
hbmScaled = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, HORZRES) * 0.5, GetDeviceCaps(hDC, VERTRES) * 0.5);

ReleaseDC(MainWnd,hDC);
EndPaint(MainWnd,&Painter);

free(DisplayImage);
free(bm_info);
}
```

The following is a link I found on resizing/rescaling images, but I don't understand how to implement it using my code.

[C++ WIN32: Rescaling Bitmaps/Giving Bitmaps HDC's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932142/c-win32-rescaling-bitmaps-giving-bitmaps-hdcs)

Please advise.

Comment: The Windows API doesn't have good support for resizing images, except maybe GDI+.  You'll have better luck finding a library dedicated to the task.

Comment: `StretchBlt` might work. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/scaling-an-image

Comment: `GDI+` for the win

Comment: @mar Just because you stopped having an interest in following the Windows API doesn't mean that the support you claim to not be there weren't. It is, and you can see it in action every single time you hover over a taskbar button. Them thumbnails look a lot like scaled images to me.

Comment: @IInspectable when I said "good support", I didn't mean it couldn't do it.  I simply meant that the standard tools like `StretchBlt` did a bad job of it.  Those thumbnails you speak of are produced by DWM, and only apply to a whole window.  I'm not sure if or how you could access that from a user program.

Comment: @mar The taskbar thumbnails were an example. I wasn't suggesting that they were immediately applicable to this problem. The underlying technology ([DXGI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi)) is, though. You can load any image onto a DX surface and present it at any given size. That's called *"scaling"*.

Answer (score 0):

The [StretchBlt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt) method is pointed out in the link.

Add the following code in `PaintImage()`,

```
void PaintImage()
{
    for (i=0; i<256; i++)
    {
        bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbBlue = bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbGreen = bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbRed = i;
        bm_info->bmiColors[i].rgbReserved=0;
    }   
    ...
    
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(MainWnd, &rc);
    hdcScaled = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    hbmScaled = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS);
    SelectObject(hdcScaled, hbmScaled);
    SetDIBitsToDevice(hdcScaled, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS, 0, 0,
        0, /* first scan line */
        DISPLAY_ROWS, /* number of scan lines */
        DisplayImage, bm_info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    SetStretchBltMode(hDC, HALFTONE);
    StretchBlt(hDC, 0, 0, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, hdcScaled, 0, 0, DISPLAY_COLS, DISPLAY_ROWS, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteObject(hdcScaled);
    DeleteObject(hbmScaled);
    ...

    
}
```

Note: Delete objects to avoid memory leaks

Comment: This is using point-sampling, producing visual artifacts peculiar to point-sampling. Depending on the source image contents and source-destination-ratios the image degradation can range anywhere from barely noticeable to completely butchered. Something you need to be aware of, so that you can select a different stretch mode if necessary.

Comment: Thank you! I've used this code, and it works fine. But, I found that there are random black pixels here and there like noise. How do I fix that?

Comment: @NiraliBandaru  Maybe you can try to add `SetStretchBltMode(hDC, HALFTONE);` above `StretchBlt` and see if it improve image quality. If it doesn't work, please update your question and add the corresponding image.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CAPI](https://github.com/b-sullender/CAPI) library. It has a very easy to use image stretch functions

- capi_DrawImageEx
- capi_DrawImageExA

Here is a simple example program that demonstrates stretching an image to fit into a window.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <CAPI.h>

#define WinClassName STR("ExampleProgram")
#define WinTitle STR("Example Program")

#ifdef  UNICODE
#define app_fopen _wfopen_s
#define app_printf wprintf
#define ApplicationEntryPoint wWinMain
#else
#define app_fopen fopen_s
#define app_printf printf
#define ApplicationEntryPoint WinMain
#endif //  UNICODE

static HWND Window_hWnd = 0;
static HDC BufferHDC = 0;
static BITMAPINFO* pDisplayBitmap = 0;
static HBITMAP hBitmap = 0;

static int ClientWidth;
static int ClientHeight;
static IMAGE FrameBuffer;

static IMAGE exampleImage;

void* LoadFile(const STRING* FilePath, U64* pFileSize)
{
    FILE* Stream;
    size_t BufferLength;
    void* pThisFile;
    void* pNewBlock;

    if ((FilePath == 0) || (pFileSize == 0)) return 0;

    *pFileSize = 0;

    if (app_fopen(&Stream, FilePath, STR("rb")) != 0) return 0;
    if (Stream == 0) return 0;

    pThisFile = 0;
    BufferLength = 0;

    do
    {
        BufferLength += 0x1000;

        pNewBlock = capi_realloc(pThisFile, BufferLength);
        if (pNewBlock == 0)
        {
            if (pThisFile != 0) capi_free(pThisFile);
            fclose(Stream);
            return 0;
        }

        pThisFile = pNewBlock;

        *pFileSize += fread(&((U8*)pThisFile)[*pFileSize], 1, 0x1000, Stream);
    } while (!(feof(Stream)));

    fclose(Stream);

    return pThisFile;
}

I32 SaveFile(const STRING* FilePath, void* pFilePointer, U64 FileSize)
{
    FILE* Stream;
    size_t nBytesWrite;
    I32 ErrorCode;

    if ((FilePath == 0) || (pFilePointer == 0) || (FileSize == 0)) return CAPI_ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    ErrorCode = CAPI_ERROR_NONE;

    if (app_fopen(&Stream, FilePath, STR("w+b")) != 0) return CAPI_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
    if (Stream == 0) return CAPI_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;

    nBytesWrite = fwrite(pFilePointer, 1, (size_t)FileSize, Stream);
    if (nBytesWrite != FileSize)
    {
        ErrorCode = CAPI_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED;
        goto exit_func;
    }

exit_func:
    fclose(Stream);

    return ErrorCode;
}

void FreeSysInternal()
{
    if (BufferHDC != 0)
    {
        DeleteDC(BufferHDC);
        BufferHDC = 0;
    }

    if (pDisplayBitmap != 0)
    {
        capi_free(pDisplayBitmap);
        pDisplayBitmap = 0;
    }

    if (hBitmap != 0)
    {
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        hBitmap = 0;
    }
}

U32 SetupWindowFrameBuffer(HDC WindowHDC, RECT* ClientRt)
{
    FreeSysInternal();

    pDisplayBitmap = (BITMAPINFO*)capi_malloc(sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER));
    if (pDisplayBitmap == 0) return 1;

    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biWidth = ClientRt->right;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biHeight = -ClientRt->bottom;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biCompression = 0;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;

    BufferHDC = CreateCompatibleDC(WindowHDC);
    if (BufferHDC == 0)
    {
        capi_free(pDisplayBitmap);
        return 2;
    }

    hBitmap = CreateDIBSection(BufferHDC, pDisplayBitmap, 0,
        (void**)&FrameBuffer.Pixels, 0, 0);

    if (hBitmap == 0)
    {
        DeleteDC(BufferHDC);
        capi_free(pDisplayBitmap);
        return 3;
    }

    GdiFlush();

    FrameBuffer.ScanLine = ClientRt->right;
    FrameBuffer.Width = ClientRt->right;
    FrameBuffer.Height = ClientRt->bottom;

    SelectObject(BufferHDC, hBitmap);

    return 0;
}

void Window_Paint_Handler(IMAGE* pDisplay)
{
    // Fill the background of our window.

    capi_FillImage(pDisplay, COLOR(195, 195, 195, 255));

    // Now we stretch our test image to the size of the window.
    // Note: The last parameter (Alpha) must be 255 for the image to be displayed normally.

    capi_DrawImageExA(pDisplay, &exampleImage, 0, 0, DRAW_RESIZE_BOXSAMP, pDisplay->Width, pDisplay->Height, 255);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HDC WinDC;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT WinArea;
    RECT ClientArea;
    int BorderWidth;
    int BorderHeight;

    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_ERASEBKGND:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        WinDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &ClientArea);

        if ((ClientArea.right == 0) || (ClientArea.bottom == 0)) goto exit_paint_message;
        if ((ClientArea.right != FrameBuffer.Width) || (ClientArea.bottom != FrameBuffer.Height))
        {
            if (SetupWindowFrameBuffer(WinDC, &ClientArea) != 0) goto exit_paint_message;
        }

        Window_Paint_Handler(&FrameBuffer);

        SetDIBits(BufferHDC, hBitmap, 0,
            pDisplayBitmap->bmiHeader.biHeight, FrameBuffer.Pixels, pDisplayBitmap, 0);
        BitBlt(WinDC, 0, 0, ClientArea.right, ClientArea.bottom, BufferHDC, 0, 0, 0x00CC0020);

    exit_paint_message:
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        Window_hWnd = hWnd;

        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &WinArea);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &ClientArea);

        BorderWidth = WinArea.right - ClientArea.right;
        BorderHeight = WinArea.bottom - ClientArea.bottom;

        SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL,
            0, 0,
            BorderWidth + ClientWidth, BorderHeight + ClientHeight, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOZORDER);

        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &WinArea);

        SetWindowPos(hWnd, NULL,
            (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - (WinArea.right - WinArea.left)) / 2,
            (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - (WinArea.bottom - WinArea.top)) / 2,
            0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
        break;
    }
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI ApplicationEntryPoint(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ STRING* pCmdLine, _In_ int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    void* myLoadedFile;
    U64 FileSize;
    I32 ErrorCode;

    // Load our image to draw to the window frame buffer.

    myLoadedFile = LoadFile(STR("C:/Users/Public/myTestImage.ico"), &FileSize);
    if (myLoadedFile == 0)
    {
        MessageBox(0, STR("LoadFile Failed."), STR("Error!"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    ErrorCode = capi_LoadImageFromMemory(&exampleImage, 1, myLoadedFile, FileSize);
    if (ErrorCode != CAPI_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        MessageBox(0, STR("capi_LoadImageFromMemory Failed."), STR("Error!"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // The client area of our window will be the same size as our test image.

    ClientWidth = exampleImage.Width;
    ClientHeight = exampleImage.Height;

    // Create the display window and enter the thread/window message loop.

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = WinClassName;
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex))
    {
        MessageBox(0, STR("Failed to register the window class."), STR("Error!"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    // Note: The 700 (Width) and 500 (Height) values are just dummy values. The Width and Height get set in the WM_CREATE message handler.

    CreateWindowEx(0, WinClassName, WinTitle,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_BORDER | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SYSMENU | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,
        0, 0, 700, 500, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!Window_hWnd)
    {
        MessageBox(0, STR("Failed to create the window."), STR("Error!"), MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    FreeSysInternal();

    return 0;
}
```